# Extending a Base Controller with a different Validator

Tags: laravel, validation

So I have a Base controller that contains a  method

```
storeEntry(Request $request) {...}
```

For some type of entries, I'm creating their own controller with a different validation rules, so I'd like to:

```
storeEntry(DifferentEntryRequest $request) {...}
```

But of course I can't do that. I also had an interface for the Base Controller like

```
storeEntry(DifferentEntryRequest $request)
```

But I also ditched that.

I've tried to run the validation on the constructor of the child, but then also the get requests get validated

Doing

```
    public function __construct(DifferentEntryRequest $request)
    {
        $this-request = $request;
    }
```

Am I facing this wrongly?

My temp solution is to remove the `storeEntry()` out of the parent controller and the interface. (That's what caused me to ditch the interface completely)

Comment: Although not an absolute rule, in general you would expect each controller's methods to be unique to that controller, it's abnormal to use a parent method to process a `store` request for all controllers. Can you explain your use case, why are you re-using the same `storeEntry` method across multiple controllers? I suspect that there's a better approach to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Well I expect *almost* the entries to have the same validation rules, but 1 out of 10 could have a different set of rules. That's why I wanted a base method to store them but to keep open the possibility to override the rules.